# Automate the boring stuff with Python: Mad Libs

Tags: python

This is one of my first programs. I needed to add an exception since my for loop ended always with an "AttributeError". Ideas to get around it? I found that other people have posted their own solutions for this problem (i.e. replace keywords in a textfile), but I didn't want to just copy them.

I know there are probably ways to shorten the code but I didn't manage to figure it out (yet).

```
import re, os

#Check if a story template finns, else create a new one.
if os.path.exists('madlibstemplate.txt') == False:
    print('No story template found, creating a new file.')
    mad_libs_file = open('madlibstemplate.txt', 'w')
    mad_libs_file.write('Long time ago, the ADJECTIVE NOUN lived in the ADJECTIVE NOUN. \
There was only a neighbour: the ADJECTIVE NOUN. The neighbour decided to ADVERB VERB \
the rival. However, the ADJECTIVE NOUN managed to VERB the evil neighbour.')
    mad_libs_file.close()
else:
    print('An empty template file found!')

# Open file and save the text under 'content'
mad_libs_file = open('madlibstemplate.txt')
content = mad_libs_file.read()
# To be able to search for the placeholder keywords
mad_regex = re.compile('NOUN|ADJECTIVE|VERB|ADVERB')
search = mad_regex.search(content)
# The story is edited multiple times and saved under "result"
result = search.group()
# Just to loop the for loop enough times
amount = len(mad_regex.findall(content))

# Editing the story 'amount' times and asking to enter a replacement word
for i in range(amount):
    try:
        if result == 'NOUN':
            print('Enter a noun:')
            k = input()
            mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            content = mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            search = mad_regex.search(content)
            result = search.group()
        elif result == 'VERB':
            print('Enter a verb:')
            k = input()
            mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            content = mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            search = mad_regex.search(content)
            result = search.group()
        elif result == 'ADJECTIVE':
            print('Enter an adjective:')
            k = input()
            mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            content = mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            search = mad_regex.search(content)
            result = search.group()
        elif result == 'ADVERB':
            print('Enter an adverb:')
            k = input()
            mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            content = mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            search = mad_regex.search(content)
            result = search.group()
    except AttributeError: #Always ends with error for some reason, so an exception.
        print('\nThis is your new story: \n \n' + content + '\n')

# Creates a new file for the new story        
print('Please name your new file.')
k = input()
new_file = open('%s.txt' % (k), 'w')
new_file.write(content)
new_file.close()
```

Comment: What do you think happens when you call `mad_regex.search()` and it matches nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are not checking your return values.

```
for i in range(amount):
    try:
        if result == 'NOUN':
            print('Enter a noun:')
            k = input()
            mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            content = mad_regex.sub(k, content, 1)
            search = mad_regex.search(content)  # This returns None when it doesn't match
            result = search.group() # Search is now None, and you get your exception
```

The solution is to check the result of `mad_regex.search` and if it is `None`, don't try to update result since your loop will finish anyway due to your for loop condition.